# package installation error

Tags: installation, package-management, mysql

I was trying to install mysql server 5.6 via deb file and the software installer froze and force quited. After that when i tried to install mysql via the command

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

its giving me this error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So i tried to remove mysql via this command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After then when i was trying to setup mysql its giving me this errors

```
The package mysql needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --configure -a` does not *remove* any software: (from the man page)

```
--configure package...|-a|--pending
          Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet  config‐
          ured.   If  -a  or  --pending  is  given instead of package, all
          unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
```

That does not revert nor continue the work you triggered by `apt-get`, but continues and completes a substep carried out by `dpkg`. After you've done that you should issue the initial `apt-get` command again.

You may have to reinstall the packages with this command (reinstalls all direct dependencies):

```
apt-get --reinstall --purge install libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
```

Also, an `apt-get update` does the trick sometimes.